# Pydantic root_validator unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, validation, pydantic, sqlmodel

I have a file `test.py` like this:

```py
from pydantic import root_validator
from sqlmodel import SQLModel
from typing import List

from devtools import debug

class Base(SQLModel):

    @root_validator(pre=True)
    def validate(cls, values):
        debug(values, type(values))
        for k, v in values.items():
            # here we perform the validation
            # for this example we do nothing
            pass
        debug("EXIT")
        return values

class A(Base):
    id: int
    name: str

class B(Base):
    id: int
    others: List[A]
```

Now if I do

```
$ python3

Python 3.10.5 (v3.10.5:f377153967, Jun  6 2022, 12:36:10) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> from test import A
>>> from test import B
>>> x = A(id=1, name="john")

test.py:11 Base.validate
    values: {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'john',
    } (dict) len=2
    type(values): <class 'dict'> (type)
test.py:16 Base.validate
    'EXIT' (str) len=4

>>> y = B(id=42, others=[])

test.py:11 Base.validate
    values: {
        'id': 42,
        'others': [],
    } (dict) len=2
    type(values): <class 'dict'> (type)
test.py:16 Base.validate
    'EXIT' (str) len=4

>>> z = B(id=100, others=[x])

test.py:11 Base.validate
    values: {
        'id': 42,
        'others': [
            A(
                id=1,
                name='john',
            ),
        ],
    } (dict) len=2
    type(values): <class 'dict'> (type)
test.py:16 Base.validate
    'EXIT' (str) len=4
test.py:11 Base.validate
    values: A(
        id=1,
        name='john',
    ) (A)
    type(values): <class 'test.A'> (SQLModelMetaclass)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/yuri/Desktop/exact/fractal/fractal-common/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlmodel/main.py", line 498, in __init__
    values, fields_set, validation_error = validate_model(
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 1077, in pydantic.main.validate_model
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 895, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.validate
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 928, in pydantic.fields.ModelField._validate_sequence_like
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 1094, in pydantic.fields.ModelField._validate_singleton
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 884, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.validate
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 1101, in pydantic.fields.ModelField._validate_singleton
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 1148, in pydantic.fields.ModelField._apply_validators
  File "pydantic/class_validators.py", line 318, in pydantic.class_validators._generic_validator_basic.lambda13
  File "/Users/yuri/Desktop/exact/fractal/fractal-common/test.py", line 12, in validate
    for k, v in values.items():
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I don't undestand what is happening with `z`. Why after calling the validator for class `B`, the constructor call the validator also for class `A` but this time `values` is not a dict but a `<class 'test.A'> (SQLModelMetaclass)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with SQLModel per se, but is an issue that `SQLModel` inherits from Pydantic's `BaseModel`.

You are breaking regular model validation by overriding the [`BaseModel.validate`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.5/pydantic/main.py#L684) method. It serves a special purpose. When you have a model field annotated with another model, like your `B.others` being of type `list[A]`, the outer (`B`) model will call the inner (`A`) model's `validate` method.

That method is designed as a ["normal" validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/) method, i.e. the value to be validated will be passed to it as the first positional argument. In this case that value is your `A` model instance `x` that you passed for in the list for `others`. That is why it shows `<class 'test.A'>` as the type of `values`. (Don't know why it mentions the metaclass as well, but I guess that is just what this `debug` function does.)

The solution is very simple: Name your root validator method something else that does *not* override a built-in method of `BaseModel`. This is also a good idea from a semantic perspective because `validate` is not very descriptive. Try and indicate what it does on top of normal model validation in its name.

But even just changing the method name to `foo` will fix your error.